# The Type Or Namespace name 'SimpleCrypto' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I think the question title is self explanatory. i was trying to encrypt the user password on MVC4 but i keep on getting the error message

> 'The Type Or Namespace name 'SimpleCrypto' could not be found'

on this line

```
var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
```

here is the code

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    using (var dc = new MMT.Models.StatusFollowUPEntitiesUser())
    {
        var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
        var encrypPass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);
        var newUser = dc.tblUsers.Create();
        newUser.Email = user.Email;
        newUser.Password = encrypPass;
        newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;
        newUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        newUser.LastName = user.LastName;
        newUser.MiddleName = user.MiddleName;
        newUser.Role = user.Role;
        newUser.UserCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        newUser.Active = true;
        //newUser.IPAddress = ;
        dc.tblUsers.Add(newUser);
        dc.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check your usings?

Comment: Are you sure you really add it's nuget package and it's using directive?

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes, the package is intalled.

Comment: @PhilippM using System.Security.Cryptography;

Comment: Using local time in `newUser.UserCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;` is almost certainly a bad idea. When identifying points in time, store them as UTC and only convert them to local time when displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your project has reference to SimpleCrypto.dll.
If not, then install package into your project (type in package manager console):

```
Install-Package SimpleCrypto
```